# why am I getting undefined at the moment when I click my button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to try to display my notification json through ajax, but however when I try first show me undefined, and then show me my json what am I doing wrong?

```
$(function (doc, win, $) {
    var notification = win.Notification || win.mozNotification || win.webkitNotification;
    var $badge = $("#notifications-badge");
    var $list = $("#notifications-list");
    var $button = $("#notifications-button");
    URL_GET_NOTIFICATION = BASE_URL + 'notifications/getNotification';

    function check_notifications() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: URL_GET_NOTIFICATION,
            //data: { timestamp : timestamp },
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }

   $button.click(function (e) {
      alert(check_notifications());
   });

}(document, window, jQuery));
```

Comment: The check notification function does not have a callback that's the only problem I can see

Comment: how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

All functions return `undefined` by default when called, unless something else is specified.

You'd get the same with just

```js
function go() {};

alert( go() ); // undefined
```

And that's basically what you're doing, alerting a function that doesn't return anything.

If you return something from the function, it works

```js
function go() { return 'Hello Kitty' };

alert( go() ); // Hello Kitty
```

***But***, as you're using ajax inside the function, you can't really return the result from that, as it's asynchronous and executes some time after the result is returned.

You'd have to use a callback or promise to make it work.

```
function check_notifications() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: URL_GET_NOTIFICATION,
        //data: { timestamp : timestamp },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}

$button.click(function (e) {
   check_notifications().done(function(data) {
      alert(data);
   });
});
```

As a sidenote, use the console when debugging, not alerts.

Comment: If you use the exact code above, it still alerts `undefined`? Are you returning JSON from the server

Comment: yea , i am returning json from server